# iOS Integration with Facebook - Publishing in the news feed

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios5

I don'y know if here is the right place to ask that, but i'm pretty sure that some of you already experienced some kind of iOS integration with Facebook.... Then I'll try to explain what i'm trying to do here....

I've already connected my app with facebook following the documentation in Developers.facebook..... The thing is.... I have a button in my app that should trigger the dialog box that allows me to publish in my news feed.... The problem is that the information in the documentation doesn't work (Or I don't know how to use it...)....

The orientation there is to use that code to trigger the action:

```
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  kAppId, @"app_id",
  @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
  @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
  @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
  @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
  @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
  @"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",  @"message",
  nil];

[_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

But that's a lot of things missing on the information, like: where should I use that code and how exactly....

Someone have already done that kind of thing?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you should do for this to work is make an IBAction an couple it in the Xib to the button and behaviour you want.

it would look something like this :

```
-(IBAction) sendMessageToWall
{
   NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  kAppId, @"app_id",
  @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
  @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
  @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
  @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
  @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
  @"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",  @"message",
  nil];

  [_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

}
```

Comment: which error? I didn't see in the question that you received an error

Comment: I've done exactly that, but this errors appears: "Use of undeclared identifier 'kAppid'" , " Expect ';' at end of declaration", "Expression result unused", "extraneous ']' before ';'" , " unknown receiver '_facebook'" and "No know class method for selector 'dialog andParams:andDelegate'" ----- That's the problem.... I don't know what should I do to fix it.... But thanks for your answer!

Comment: first of all kAppid is a konstant (hence the k ;-)) that signifies your appid as determined by the app that you created in facebook. (The same id you probably allready needed to define in the plist) Most of the time such a "k" property is defined in your prefix header so you can use it everywhere. do something like #define kAppid 689930303 over there (no semicolon needed). Try to do this and see which errors remain.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the tip! I'm kind of new in this.... :)!! But what about the _facebook and andParams:andDelegates..... Do you have any idea what's happening here? Thanks again!

Comment: Does the problem persist after the changes? Did you declare your _facebook class? did you allocate and initiate it correctly? if so it should be working now ;-). If not it is quite some work and i can't really explain it better that it is explained here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/  :-)

Comment: I did this and it woks for the first part.... But the only think remaining here is the error about the "_facebook and andParams:andDelegates"..... The error is "Unknow receiver '_facebook'" and "No know class method for selector 'dialog:andParameters:andDelegate:'"